# find exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am not Mathematician, So hope  I can use the right terms to explain my problem.

How to find exponential equation where sum of the equation from 1 to 100 is known (some number).

Example
Lets say I need sum of equation from 1 to 5
suppose my equation is y = x^2;

```
1^2 =1
2^2= 4 
3^2 = 9
4^2 = 16
5^2 = 25
So the sum here 2+4+9+16+25 = 55
```

In the example I know the equation and calculated the sum from 1 to 5. I am looking for reverse method, I know the sum I want to find the equation.

Comment: What do you mean by 'sum of the equation'?

Comment: Do you mean $a^1+a^2+\cdots+a^{99}+a^{100}=b$ where $b$ is some number?

Comment: The sum of squares up to $n$ is $S=\dfrac{n^3}3+\dfrac{n^2}2+\dfrac{n}6$. The exact inversion formula is very complicated. An easier way is to use the approximation $n\approx\sqrt[3]{3S}$ and check with the nearest integer. E.g. if $S=42925$, the approximation is $50.49\cdots$ and the true value $50$.

For exponent $k$, use $n\approx\sqrt[k]{kS}$.

Comment: $1^2=1$, not $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Being tricky, write
$$S=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1)=\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ and use series reversion and obtain
$$n=t-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{12 t}-\frac{1}{5184
   t^5}+\cdots\qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\sqrt[3]{3S}$$
Using, as @Yves Daoust in comments, $S=42925$ this truncated series would give
$$n=49.999999999999999981\cdots$$ If you want more accuracy, use for example
$$S=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1)=\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$ and repeat the inversion process to get
$$n= t-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{12 t}-\frac{1}{5184 t^5}+\frac{1}{62208
   t^7}+\cdots \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\sqrt[3]{3S}$$ and, for the same value of $S$
$$n=50.000000000000000000000000027\cdots$$ and we could continue for ever.

If you want the exact result, solve the cubic equation in $n$ and the solution is
$$n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(36 \sqrt{3} S\right)\right)-\frac 12$$